# Expo Notification getting issues when building in apk

Tags: expo, expo-notifications

I'm new here. I'm just hoping someone can help with my issue. I created an app that was supposed to have push notifications. The problem is that it perfectly works on Expo Go, but once I build the apk and test it on a physical device, there is no push notification happening. So I tried to create a fresh Expo app and follow the documentation. This fresh Expo app only has a minimal setup. I literally just copied and pasted the code in this link: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#android. Still the issue remains